# Hindi Text in Eclipse on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, unicode, hindi

How can one directly input Hindi text into the eclipse IDE on android?

I would like to type Hindi text directly into the eclipse IDE without copy/pasting it from somewhere else, [see this demo](http://transliteration.techinfomatics.com) for an example of writing Hindi text quickly.

I would like to do the same thing in the eclipse IDE.

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: i want to write hindi text direct in eclipse IDE without copy paste hindi text from another place

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR write hindi text?? You  need to use noto fonts to display hindi fonts.https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/style/typography.html. To type hindi fonts say in edittext you needs a custom keyboard that supports the same and read this http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: http://transliteration.techinfomatics.com/ that show demo for write hindi text fastly .so that type of technology i want to use in my eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i found solution of my question.

> i found that Google develop many inputtools for windows OS , Android
>   and for Web in many language that use for fastly type any language with the help of English typing.

So i download inputtools at URL : [Download Page](http://google.com/inputtools/windows/) thank you Everyone for help me

Answer (score 2):

Use hindi texts inside String.xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="hindiText"> पवन कुमार</string>

</resources>
```

And use this on your app's TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hindiText"
    android:textSize="28sp" />
```

Comment: But How to write hindi text in xml file "पवन कुमार".how to write text in hindi directly in eclipse.

Comment: install hindi on your system, then you can write on string files. Otherwise hire a translator if you don't know hindi.

Comment: i know hindi language but which tool is useful for install hindi in our system?

Comment: http://indiatyping.com/index.php/download/download-hindi-typing-software ...maybe it will work

Answer (score 1):

Yes Hindi language can support in Android devices. You need to follow the steps.

**Step 1:**

Just create one values folder under resources like `values-hi` and add strings.xml file inside of this folder. You can add your translated strings in this strings.xml file.

example

```
<string name="your_text">अपका संदेशर</string>
```

**Step 2:**

If you call your strings from the other layout xml files then just call like the following

```
android:ext="@string/your_string"
```

**Step 3:**

You can also use string values in java code programmatically.

Comment: But How to write hindi text in xml file "अपका संदेशर" .

Comment: I Just copy and paste the hindi words in xml file. I can be sure no one will know all the language so better copy and paste. But surely there is a way to type hindi words..

Comment: i'm saying  only working English and HIndi .not All Language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking forward for multi-language(English AND Hindi) support for your application. If so, [image]

strings.xml in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="welcome">accueil</string>
    <string name="email">adresse e-mail</string>
    <string name="password">mot de passe</string>
    <string name="login">connexion</string>
    <string name="signup">Ne pas avoir un compte? signer</string>

</resources>
```

strings.xml in values-hi folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="welcome">स्वागतम</string>
    <string name="email">ईमेल पता</string>
    <string name="password">पासवर्ड</string>
    <string name="login">लॉगिन</string>
    <string name="signup">खाता नहीं है? साइन अप करें</string>

</resources>
```

for more references please check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/)

**EDIT** (as per the comment)

Try this

1.Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the default encoding for all content types.
2.Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding" to "Other : UTF-8".

For more references, please check this 
[blog](https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/)

Comment: http://transliteration.techinfomatics.com that show demo for write hindi text fastly .so that type of technology i want to use in my eclipse IDE

Comment: i'm telling you demo what i want.but transliteration can not work in android because i've tried many time so i want another thing that will work as Google transliteration.then why edit my question?

Comment: I think that is not available in eclipse now., you can request for the same to eclipse team to include or release a plugin for the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Use UTF-8 encoding in android studio , below is setting page , using
>   utf-8 encoding will allow you to paste hindi fonts in xml and java
>   code.

[image]

For Eclipse IDE : below is path to configure the encoding :

```
Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding
```

Comment: sry not in android Studio.In eclipse IDE